# Why did I need only to import child class from module without importing its base class and its properties from another instance?

Tags: python, class, import, module

> Python Crash Course: A Hands-On, Project-Based Introduction to
> Programming

When I read this book, I had a question.

Why did I need only to import 'Admin' from 'admin'?

In my opinion, the first line code in 'test.py'  means that it only copys the class 'Admin' code.

Thus, the second and third line code won't run successfully because it doesn't conclude the code block 'from user import User' and the defination of class 'Privileges'.

Any help will be appreciated!

**test.py**

```
from admin import Admin  # line 1


my_admin = Admin('Jade', 'Lam', 'male', '22')  # line 2

my_admin.privileges.show_privileges()  # line 3
print('\n')
```

**admin.py**

```
from user import User


class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, sex, age):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, sex, age)
        self.privileges = Privileges()


class Privileges():
    def __init__(self):
        self.privileges = ['can add post', 'can delete post',
                           'can ban user']

    def show_privileges(self):
        print("Admin's privileges: ")
        for privilege in self.privileges:
            print("--" + privilege)
```

**user.py**

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, sex, age):
        self.first_name = first_name.title()
        self.last_name = last_name.title()
        self.sex = sex
        self.age = age

    def describe_user(self):
        --snip--

    def greet_user(self):
        --snip--
```

Comment: When you import a module the first time, the whole module is loaded, but with the `from admin import Admin` form, you just kept a reference to the name Admin in the current namespace. But the whole code of the module still runs.

Comment: At least the executable statements of it.

Comment: thanks! Although I don't know the principle of its running.

Comment: See the example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

See the example below.

```
# Consider this module:

# mod1.py:
# some outer level code
# gets executed

pass

# functions get defined but do not execute
# unless called from above


def f1():
    pass


def f2():
    pass


# classes get defined and actually execute but
# if they only have defs, again those get defined
# but don't run.


class A:
    pass


class B:
    pass


class C:
    pass


# now main.py:
# mod1 executes. Every name of mod1 also becomes  available
# under the prefix 'mod1.' This is like creating a mod1 namespace
# in outer scope of main.
import mod1

# mod1 only runs once on imports in this module, so this time it won't
# (it already has).
# While you can still access every name from mod1 using the mod1 prefix
# from the above import, below only the A name is kept in the outer scope
# of main.
from mod1 import A

# If A has dependencies on other mod1 names, that does not matter here.
# Those dependencies were solved on mod1 run, and all the names involved
# were accessed as needed at mod1 runtime. These names are actually in a
# different scope that belongs to mod1.

# After imports, main can have mod1 names in its scope, but mod1 never
# had access to main names. Unless it imports main, something it should
# not do to avoid circular imports.
```

Hope you understand it now.